# Version number of Git commit from a specific branch in TeamCity 8.x

Tags: java, git, teamcity, continuous-delivery

I am building a Continuous Delivery pipeline in TC, and as a 0th build step, I'd like to be able to extract the unique version number which I give to my commit.

It looks like this: release_4.46.

I'd like to use the '4.46'-part to append to the different steps of my pipeline, and as the final step, name my artifact as e.g. app_4.46.war.

I've managed to assemble the majority of the pipeline(unit tests, jsHint, Maven build) and it's up and running, but I cannot get to the end of this feature.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Use [git describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) for such purposes. It's not quite what you want but can give satisfactory results

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a powershell step which extracts 4.46 from branch name and set a teamcity parameter which can be used in rest of the steps. Powershell code should looks something like:

```
function Set-Version{
    param
    (       
        [string]
        $branch
    )   
    $ExtractedVersion = $branch.Split("_")[1]
    Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='ExtractedVersion' value='$ExtractedVersion']"
}
```

And then in the powershell step you can call this function like

```
Set-Version %teamcity.build.branch%
```

Once this step is executed, a teamcity parameter ExtractedVersion with value 4.46 should be available for the rest of the build steps.